# PHP - I get true on (0=='undefined') , why?

Tags: php

if you run this code:

```
if ( 0=='undefined') echo 'true'; else echo 'false';
```

you get 'true' which means int 0 equals the string 'undefined'.

Why is that? what am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types) documents that when comparing `0` and `"undefined"`, both are converted to numbers first. And [this section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) says that `"undefined"` converts to the number `0`:

> If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value
>   used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

So the results of the comparison are expected, if somewhat surprising for someone new to PHP.

If you want the comparison to return `false` because the two operands are not of the same type, PHP provides the [identical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `===` that does exactly this.

Comment: +1 - it's worth pointing out that the string's value doesn't matter as long as it doesn't contain anything that can be converted into an integer though.

Comment: adding: you can use `===` to actually take the types into account, but then you should know that `0==='0'` would return false.

Comment: @Pekka: we were probably typing at the same time :)