# How to pass an array to jQuery with wp_localize_script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I have this function defined in `functions.php`

```
    function cn_add_script($postsperpage) {

        // find all of the published posts
        $publishedposts = get_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=-1');
        // count the published posts
        $count = count($publishedposts);
        // only run this function on 'page-bulletins.php'
        if( is_page_template('page-bulletins.php') ) {
            // not entirely sure what this does, I think this tells Wordpress to use URLs with '/page/#' and also recognizes what page the user is currently viewing.
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            // divide the total number of posts by the posts per page, then round this number up ('ceil' does this)
            $maxpages = ceil($count/$postsperpage);
            // store the next page number in a variable
            $nextpagecalc = $paged + 1;
            // if the next page number is greater than the max number of pages
            if( $nextpagecalc > $maxpages ) {
                // code to be finalized; store an empty path if there are no more pages to show
                $nextpage = '';
            }
            else {
                // if there is a next page, put the path for it in a variable
                $nextpage = get_bloginfo('url').'/bulletins/page/'.$nextpagecalc.'/';
            }

        }

        $array = ['startPage', 'maxPages', 'nextLink'];
        $array = array (
            'startPage' =>  $paged,
            'maxPages'  =>  $maxpages,
            'nextLink'  =>  $nextpage
        );

        wp_register_script (
            // handle name for script (to be used later to localize the script)
            'cnLoadPosts',
            // location of the script
            get_bloginfo('template_url').'/_/js/functions-ajax-ck.js'
        );
        // call the script defined above
        wp_enqueue_script ('cnLoadPosts');
        // in the script defined above, define a handle that Javascript can use
        wp_localize_script ('cnLoadPosts', 'cnPageAdvance', $array);

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cn_add_script' );
```

I am trying to pass the values of `$paged`, `$maxpages` and `$nextpage` to the file `functions-ajax-ck.js` using wp_enqueue_scripts. When I use `print_r($array)` I get the following output which I expect:

```
Array ( [startPage] => 1 [maxPages] => 4 [nextLink] => http://localhost:8888/slfiber/bulletins/page/2/ )
```

However, this information does not make it to the `functions-ajax-ck.js` file as verified with inspecting the element:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var cnPageAdvance = {"startPage":"1","maxPages":"0","nextLink":""};
/* ]]> */
```

For reference, this is the code in the `.js` file:

```
    (function($) {
        $(window).load(function() {
            // The number of the next page to load (/page/x/).
            var pageNum = parseInt(cnPageAdvance.startPage) + 1;
            // The maximum number of pages the current query can return.
            var max = parseInt(cnPageAdvance.maxPages);
            // The link of the next page of posts.
            var nextLink = cnPageAdvance.nextLink;
            $('#loadmore').click(function() {
                alert(max);
            });
        });
    })(window.jQuery);
```

If I replace `$paged`, `$maxpages` and `$nextpage` with "1", "5", and "http://wwwgoogle.com", respectively, the values pass through just fine.

How can I get $array, which holds the values of my variables, to pass through to my `js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function does not receive any parameters when you hook it via `wp_enqueue_scripts` so you're basically doing a division by zero at 
`$maxpages = ceil($count/$postsperpage);`.

that makes `$maxpages` `undefined` which is equal to `0` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471302/php-i-get-true-on-0-undefined-why)).

and that leads `if( $nextpagecalc > $maxpages )` to become true, so your `$nextpage` becomes empty.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Are you suggesting that I pass the array to javascript through a different method other than `wp_enqueue_scripts`? If so, can you point me in that direction? Thanks again.

Comment: I think it would be ideal if you did the processing that you do in the first part of the function in another place, but if that's not an option grab the value for $postsperpage from somewhere else because that's the cause for your problems.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed eliminating that variable. This totally solves the problem.

Comment: sure thing! by the way, you don't need this part "$array = ['startPage', 'maxPages', 'nextLink'];". you're creating an indexed array with that line, but you replace it with an associative array in the next line.